# Update cached monorepo node_modules in docker volume

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, caching, monorepo

I have a problem with updating `node_modules` that are shared as a docker volume in nx monorepo.

```yaml
services:
  service-a:
    container_name: service-a
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - node-modules:/app/node_modules
  service-b:
    container_name: service-b
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - node-modules:/app/node_modules
volumes:
  node-modules:
```

```
FROM node:14-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

# start app
CMD npm run nx serve ${APP_NAME} --host 0.0.0.0
```

`Service-a` and `service-b` run two nest.js applications inside docker containers, `node_modules` are shared. `Frontend` run on the host machine outside docker.

Since the volume during each build step is discarded after that step completes I cannot update packages when container is built. When I update packages I run update process on my host, then run `npm install` inside one of docker containers. It works pretty well most of the time but major updates are painful. For example when nx has some migrations then it will modify the code on host but `node_modules` inside container are untouched. When I try to run docker container it might fail (new code run with old packages) so I will be unable to run `npm install` inside that container.

I might create special docker container that will run and hang (like `tail -f /dev/null`) and then execute `docker exec update-service npm install`.

Do you have better idea to solve this issue?

Comment: Delete the `volumes:` blocks entirely.  Make sure you `RUN npm ci` in your Dockerfile instead, so the `node_modules` tree is in the image.  `docker-compose build` will rebuild the image once you've run the unit tests in your host development environment.

Comment: Will it be shared across service-a and service-b?

Comment: If they have the same `image:` or if they `build:` the same source tree, they will have the same `node_modules`.